# unable to fetch data from hive through java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jdbc, hive

i am using Ubuntu 14.04, hadoop-1.2.1([Single node](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)), hive-1.1.0([Stable 1.1.0](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/how-to-install-apache-hive/)), eclipse IDE

i have created a java project and imported all the external jar files in

> /usr/local/hive/lib/
>
> /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar

my java code looks like:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
 
public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
    // describe table
    sql = "describe " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }
 
    // load data into table
    // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
    // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
    String filepath = "/tmp/a.txt";
    sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 
    // select * query
    sql = "select * from " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }
 
    // regular hive query
    sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
  }
}
```

on running this program in eclipse i am getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)   at
> hive_demo.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:15)

how to load jdbc driver for hive?

Comment: Are you sure you have `hive-jdbc-0.14.0.jar` (or the right version for your hadoop release) in the `/usr/local/hive/lib` directory, **and have declared in Eclipse the jars in the classpath**? The classpath can be set specifically in the "Classpath" tab in "Run configurations..."

Comment: @Abbé Résina i have downloaded hive from http://apache.petsads.us/hive/stable/